# c++ boost asio sync write in async_receive handler

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost-asio

Originally, I was asking - is it possible to execute boost::asio::write() within a socket's async_receive() handler? This is happening on a single io_service, in a single thread. I have some code that's written to do this, and *I thought* it was hanging on the write() call. But I forgot to press the play button on my game (this is for a little client-server game)! But this doesn't quite fit with my understanding of boost asio, so I'll leave the question up, but asking, why does this work?

At first, I thought this couldn't be done, because the thread cannot handle the write() call since the io_service is already busy with this asynch_receive() job. I thought I would need another thread executing io_service.run(), that one could handle the write(). Apparently, that's not the case.

As I remember it, a thread will only execute jobs in an io_service one-at-a-time. If that's the case, and my app is working, then it must be that once you've begun executing the async handler, your job is already moved out of the queue. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Think about underlying I/O operations which are called by Boost using OS-specific API: sockets, serial communications or any other. There is no anything that prevents us to call send or WriteFile API from the same thread where data is received. The only side effect I can think about is when send operation hangs for a long time, blocking receiver thread. But this can happen only if the whole communication channel stopped working, so it doesn't really matter.